# checking memory_limit in PHP

Tags: php, memory-limit

I'm need to check if `memory_limit` is at least `64M` in my script installer. This is just part of PHP code that should work, but probably due to this "M" it's not reading properly the value. How to fix this ?

```
  //memory_limit
    echo "<phpmem>";
    if(key_exists('PHP Core', $phpinfo))
    {
        if(key_exists('memory_limit', $phpinfo['PHP Core']))
        {
            $t=explode(".", $phpinfo['PHP Core']['memory_limit']);
            if($t[0]>=64)
                $ok=1;
            else
                $ok=0;
            echo "<val>{$phpinfo['PHP Core']['memory_limit']}</val><ok>$ok</ok>";
        }
        else
           echo "<val></val><ok>0</ok>";
    }
    else
        echo "<val></val><ok>0</ok>";
    echo "</phpmem>\n";
```

Comment: I'm using XML code, so that's not possible.

Comment: Can you show `var_dump($phpinfo);`, or at least `var_dump($phpinfo['PHP Core']);`, so we can see what you're starting with?

Comment: The memory limit ini rule is removed from PH8-cli, it is now unlimited (return -1, false, no limits)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try to convert the value first (eg: 64M -> 64 * 1024 * 1024). After that, do comparison and print the result.

```
<?php
$memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
if (preg_match('/^(\d+)(.)$/', $memory_limit, $matches)) {
    if ($matches[2] == 'M') {
        $memory_limit = $matches[1] * 1024 * 1024; // nnnM -> nnn MB
    } else if ($matches[2] == 'K') {
        $memory_limit = $matches[1] * 1024; // nnnK -> nnn KB
    }
}

$ok = ($memory_limit >= 64 * 1024 * 1024); // at least 64M?

echo '<phpmem>';
echo '<val>' . $memory_limit . '</val>';
echo '<ok>' . ($ok ? 1 : 0) . '</ok>';
echo '</phpmem>';
```

**Please note that the above code is just an idea.** Don't forget to handle -1 (no memory limit), integer-only value (value in bytes), G (value in gigabytes), k/m/g (value in kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes because shorthand is case-insensitive), etc.

Comment: The provided regular expression is incomplete, inprecise and will lead to wrong results on various installations.

Comment: ini_get() function throws an exception in some servers do you have any adjustment on this?

Comment: Remember to handle memory_limit of -1

Comment: '$ok = ($memory_limit >= 640 * 1024 * 1024); // at least 64M?' You mean at least 640M?

Answer (score 98):

Checking on command line:

```
php -i | grep "memory_limit"
```

Comment: Are you able to explain the output I get from this: memory_limit => -1 => -1

Comment: For some PHP settings -1 means "no limit" but I'm not sure about memory_limit. You can check it from your php.ini file. Execute php -i | grep "php.ini" on command line and check memory_limit in your Loaded Configuration File.

Comment: If terminal print => -1 => -1 this indicate memory limit is unlimited

Answer (score 32):

**1. PHP-CLI:**

Command line to check ini:

```
$ php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit');"
```

Or check php-cli info and grep `memory_limit` value:

```
$ php -i | grep "memory_limit"
```

**2. PHP-FPM:**

Paste this line into `index.php` or **any php file that can be viewed on a browser**, then check the result:

```
<?php echo ini_get('memory_limit');
```

An alternative way is using `phpinfo()`:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

then find for `memory_limit` value
[image]

Comment: FYI this returns the memory limit for the CLI version of PHP, but your nginx/apache will use the "other" PHP process, the `fpm`version of PHP (sorry no idea who to describe this). Better check manually in both .ini: `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`

Answer (score 16):

Here is another simpler way to check that.

```
$memory_limit = return_bytes(ini_get('memory_limit'));
if ($memory_limit < (64 * 1024 * 1024)) {
    // Memory insufficient      
}

/**
* Converts shorthand memory notation value to bytes
* From http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php
*
* @param $val Memory size shorthand notation string
*/
function return_bytes($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    $val = substr($val, 0, -1);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }
    return $val;
}
```

Comment: what about this?


`$bytes = (int)$mem * 1024 ** ['k' => 1, 'm' => 2, 'g' => 3][strtolower($mem)[-1]] ?? 0;`

Answer (score 8):

very old post. but i'll just leave this here:

```
/* converts a number with byte unit (B / K / M / G) into an integer */
function unitToInt($s)
{
    return (int)preg_replace_callback('/(\-?\d+)(.?)/', function ($m) {
        return $m[1] * pow(1024, strpos('BKMG', $m[2]));
    }, strtoupper($s));
}

$mem_limit = unitToInt(ini_get('memory_limit'));
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as your array `$phpinfo['PHP Core']['memory_limit']` contains the value of [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/http://php.net/memory_limit), it does work the following:

- The last character of that value can signal the shorthand notation. If it's an invalid one, it's ignored.
- The beginning of the string is converted to a number in PHP's own specific way: Whitespace ignored etc.
- The text between the number and the shorthand notation (if any) is ignored.

Example:

```
# Memory Limit equal or higher than 64M?
$ok = (int) (bool) setting_to_bytes($phpinfo['PHP Core']['memory_limit']) >= 0x4000000;

/**
 * @param string $setting
 *
 * @return NULL|number
 */
function setting_to_bytes($setting)
{
    static $short = array('k' => 0x400,
                          'm' => 0x100000,
                          'g' => 0x40000000);

    $setting = (string)$setting;
    if (!($len = strlen($setting))) return NULL;
    $last    = strtolower($setting[$len - 1]);
    $numeric = (int) $setting;
    $numeric *= isset($short[$last]) ? $short[$last] : 1;
    return $numeric;
}
```

Details of the shorthand notation are outline in [a PHP manual's FAQ entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes) and extreme details are part of [Protocol of some PHP Memory Stretching Fun](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/protocol-of-some-php-memory-stretching-fun/).

Take care if the setting is `-1` PHP won't limit here, but the system does. So you need to decide how the installer treats that value.

Comment: This is compact code, but it breaks under PHP 7.1+: `$numeric = 0 + $setting;` throws an exception because $setting is not a numeric value because of the suffix (message is " A non well formed numeric value encountered in [...]"). in (at least) 7.2, the following works instead: `$numeric = (int)$setting;`

Comment: @GabrielMagana: Good point, it's quite some time ago I wrote that, and using (int) cast is prefereable over 0 + anyways for converting the number. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not so exact but simpler solution:

```
$limit = str_replace(array('G', 'M', 'K'), array('000000000', '000000', '000'), ini_get('memory_limit'));
if($limit < 500000000) ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
```

Comment: If you treat K as 2^10 it won't work. So it is not very universal. But thumb up for an invention.

Comment: Works quite well, because in the second line comparison you can have the same simplification. By now this works for me at a few hundred websites with image modifying plugin - the needed amount of memory is never very exact, so I check for 30% bigger number anyway and then the difference between 1024 and 1000 is just a rounding error :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in CLI memory limit:

```
cat /etc/php/[7.0]/cli/php.ini | grep "memory_limit"
```

FPM / "Normal"

```
cat /etc/php/[7.0]/fpm/php.ini | grep "memory_limit"
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for inspiration.

I had the same problem and instead of just copy-pasting some function from the Internet, I wrote an open source tool for it. Feel free to use it or provide feedback!

https://github.com/BrandEmbassy/php-memory

Just install it using Composer and then you get the current PHP memory limit like this:

```
$configuration = new \BrandEmbassy\Memory\MemoryConfiguration();
$limitProvider = new \BrandEmbassy\Memory\MemoryLimitProvider($configuration);
$limitInBytes = $memoryLimitProvider->getLimitInBytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

**THATS IS ANSWER**

You can check if Memory is `UNLIMITED` or `Bigger than 64M`.

```
<?php
    // is memory unlimited ? 
    function kdev_is_memory_unlimited ($memory_limit = null){
        if(empty($memory_limit))
            $memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
        return  (is_numeric($memory_limit) && (int)$memory_limit <= 0) ? true : false;
    }
    // Get Size of Memory As MB
    function get_memory_size(){
        $memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
        $unlimited = kdev_is_memory_unlimited();
        if ($unlimited){
            return true; // is unlimited!
        }else if (preg_match('/^(\d+)(.)$/', $memory_limit, $matches)) {
            if ($matches[2] == 'K') {
                $memory_limit = $matches[1] / 1024; 
            }else if ($matches[2] == 'G') {
                $memory_limit = $matches[1] * 1024; 
            }else{
                $memory_limit = $matches[1];
            }
        }
        return $memory_limit;
    }
```

get size of memory by our function

```
    $memory = get_memory_size();
```

Condition examples
If this Memory is Unlimited or bigger than 64 M

```
    if(kdev_is_memory_unlimited() || $memory >= 64)
    {
            echo "Memory Checked! Your MEMORY is " . $memory."M <br>";
    }
```

Exam 2, is memory UNLIMITED or have integer

```
    $is_memory_pass = (kdev_is_memory_unlimited() || $memory >= 64);
```

Exam 3, is memory **ONLY** UNLIMITED

```
    $is_memory_unlimited = kdev_is_memory_unlimited();
```

Exam 4, is memory **ONLY** LIMITED and WE HAVE INT

```
    $is_memory_limited = (is_numeric($memory) && $memory >= 64);
```

Exam 4 , or

```
    $is_memory_limited = (!kdev_is_memory_unlimited() && $memory >= 64);
```

Check Result

```
    echo $is_memory_pass ? "MEMORY is " . $memory."M, Thaats enough!!!" : 'You momery is lower than 64M. please increase it <br>';
```