# laravel queue:work out of memory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-4, lumen

When I run command in terminal

```
php artisan queue:work
```

I got Error:

> mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory PHP Fatal error:  Out of
>   memory (allocated 10303311872) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in
>   /var/www/html/grubily/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on
>   line 575
>
> mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory PHP Fatal error:  Out of
>   memory (allocated 10303311872) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in
>   /var/www/html/grubily/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php
>   on line 65

My Droplet Configuration is:

8 GB Memory / 40 GB Disk / NYC3 - Ubuntu WordPress 4.7 on 16.04

Also I created swap file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10208698/5476782

Answer (score 1):

Your script runs out of memory.
I suggest you optimize your code by loading in memory smaller amount of information by, for example, processing the data you load in smaller chunks.(262144 bytes is around 2.1 Mb)

If you still prefer to go on and load it all at a time, you still can increase the memory available for php:

```
$memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
ini_set('memory_limit','4M');
// process your data

// reset previous limit
ini_set('memory_limit',$meḿory_limit);
```